# How to send a string value to a function (ng-click)

Tags: angularjs

I've got a very simple questions;

Here's my HTML;

```
<button ng-click="projectTypeController.deleteProjectType(pt.Code)">X</button>
```

And my function in my controller:

```
self.deleteProjectType = function (projectTypeCode) {
    $http.post('http://localhost:49165/Service1.svc/projecttypes/delete/', projectTypeCode)
   .then(getProjectTypes)
   .then(function (response) {
   });
};
```

Code in my webservice:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "ProjectTypes/Delete/", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void DeleteProjectType(string projectTypeCode);
```

This works perfectly fine as long as 'pt.Code' is numeric, but as soon as it's a string it results in a HTTP 400 Bad Request. So I think i'm doing something wrong with the `deleteProjectType(pt.Code)` Part.

I tried to look for examples where they pass a string into a method, but i cannot find anything...

the pt.Code = a scope variable by the way, also adding data in the form of object inside a form element works fine, so passing strings in an object is not a problem, just passing a single string, instead of an integer to a method doesn't seem to work

Comment: Nope, same HTTP 400, i'm sure it's very easy... but i just cannot see it

Comment: try this  `projectTypeCode.toString()`

Comment: It seems that this is an issue in your backend. First have a look at your browser network panel, if it's sending the string, then it's not an angular issue. Have a look at your backend solution and fix the issue there.

Comment: FYI, you don't have to write sitename `http://localhost:49165/`. Just use `$http.post('Service1.svc/projec...`/

Comment: @JuhaTauriainen; My network panel doesn't show much. 
It also doesn't reach my endpoint. 
Again, when i pas an integer it works perfectly fine. 
So maybe there's something wrong with the JSON handling. 
I added this to the WCF, but doesn't seem to do the trick BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the parameter as a valid json.
To do that you can use JSON.stringify().

To implementet this in the method

```
self.deleteProjectType = function (projectTypeCode) {
    $http.post('http://localhost:49165/Service1.svc/projecttypes/delete/', JSON.stringify(projectTypeCode))
   .then(getProjectTypes)
   .then(function (response) {
   });
};
```

I prefere to use objects instead of just sending a value as a string.
If you at any time need to extend the body then you only need to add more fields to the objects and not modify the function call or the service method.
Here's an example of how you could do that

```
self.deleteProjectType = function (projectTypeCode) {
    var data = { code: projectTypeCode};
    $http.post('http://localhost:49165/Service1.svc/projecttypes/delete/', JSON.stringify(data))
   .then(getProjectTypes)
   .then(function (response) {
   });
};
```

Create the class server side

```
Public class ProjectTypeDTO
{
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

Add the class as the parameter in the service method and you are gtg

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "ProjectTypes/Delete/", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void DeleteProjectType(ProjectTypeDTO pt);
```